# How to make last row of each table's part unfinished in latex longtable?

Tags: latex, longtable

I have a table that automatically stretched over several pages by longtable package.

```
\begin{longtable}{| l | l |}
 \hline
 A & B \\ \hline
 \endfirsthead
 \multicolumn{3}{l}{Table \thetable{} -- finishing} \\ \hline
 \endhead
 a1 & b1 \\ \hline
 a1 & b2 \\ \hline
 ........
\end{longtable}
```

Suppose that table was broken (automatically) between first and second rows.
Than we have this output:

```
-------
|A | B|
-------
|a1|b1|
-------
<page break>
Table 1 -- finishing.
-------
|a2|b2|
-------
```

I want the following effect:

```
-------
|A | B|
-------
|a1|b1|

<page break>
Table 1 -- finishing.
-------
|a2|b2|
-------
```

I.e. last row of the table's first part should be unfinished (without \hline).

In general case I have a table with multiple rows with \hline after each row. What I want is to "erase" last \hline of table's first part. Or that \hline of all table's parts except the last one.

Comment: I think I'm missing exactly what you want to do... can you rephrase the question? do you want \endfoot ?

Comment: I don't know whether i can achieve this effect with \endfoot or not.
What i'm need: there should not be last horisontal line (\hline) at the
footer of table (as in example above). I.e. first part of table should be without this line, but second with it.
At the moment latex keeps this line when it breaking table. How to prevent it?

Comment: In line 5, not `\multicolumn{3}{l}` but `\multicolumn{2}{l}`.

Comment: Here, I suggest to manually comment `\hline` in `a1 & b1 \\ \hline`.